# ASP.NET runtime error after new dll files uploaded into bin folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll

I tried to add new dll files into asp.net web app bin folder and every time I get runtime error. Also, I supposed that request is pointed to some other web.config file, because when runtime error appear there's information that cannot show any error details beacuse customErros mode is not switch to off. That's not true, because I set customErrors mode to off and already checked if it works properly when application is running. ASP.NET version is the old one - 2.0, not sure what is version of IIS, it's shared hosting. After error shows up, I am deleting last added dll files so application is running again. So right now I am not able to add any new dll libraries, because of this runtime error. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: It is difficult to solve the problem without a detailed error message. I think the first thing you have to try to do is to find the error message. Did your problem appear only after you deployed it on iis?

Answer (score 1):

You as a general rule never really want to drop in bin files into the bin folder.

If you do a clean project (which one often might do), then the bin file is emptied out. If you need to include some additonal assemblies, then reference them correctly in your project. Then at build time, they will be correctly shuffled over and correctly included into the bin folder.

You really don't want to drop in some bin files into the bin folder and THEN try and reference those assemblies, since as noted, the bin folder can be cleaned out during a rebuild of the solution. So, add those bin files as references to the project.

The other issue is during a web publish, you can choose to "merge" all the .dlls into a single assembly, and once again, the bin folder is thus consisdered the resulting output of your project build - not some repostitoty location in which you start dropping in .dll's etc.

I seem some people attempt to drop in bin files into the bin folder, but you going to have nothing but problems, since as noted there are multiple issues that arise when attempting to do this.

I mean, think of nuGet additions? It creates a folder in the project folder called "packages". And you not that this folder does NOT appear in the project folder - but you don't car, since if you check references, you see that the Hodge Podge of many .dll references will point to that packages folder. At build time, then .net and the compile process figures out what .dlls are required, and THEN they are shuffled over and into the bin file.

So, if you have some .dll's you need? Create a folder at the project level, drop them in, and THEN add the references to your project - they will be correctly linked, resolved, and become part of your project at build time. And that build process is what then copies with correct references to the bin folder.

Don't try and make this a manual process. All you require is that you add + refernce the correct assemblies to the project - and the bin folder is NOT the place for such files to be referenced.

I suppose about the only exception is if you have code that at runtime is loading assemblies (.dll) via say Assembly.LoadFrom().

Even then, you can still create a folder in the project (and add these files), and include a copy on build to the bin file.

Edit:

For example, I am using the ajax tool kit. So, in project explore I see this:

[image]

If I right click on ajaxtool kit, show property sheet, we see this:

[image]

And look at that long horrible path name - absolute 100% outside of this web site. But, with copy local, then of course during the build process, then that .dll is copied to the bin folder.

Same in above say for newtonsoft (json), again, it outside of the site.

So, those assemblies referenced should thus get copied to the output (bin) folder.

However, you might be using a web site as opposed to a web site application.  (do you just open teh web site (hence: a web site).

or,
Do you open a project (sln) file, and thus have a asp.net web site application. (key difference is web site vs web site application).

However, in both cases, the .dll's should and do get copied to the output file during a build. However, if you using only a web site, then you don't have a build process in the same sense. In that case, you could consider using app_code.

I mean, you could I suppose drop in the .dll's into bin, and then reference them, but that's going to break and fall apart the first time you do a clean project - since the bin folder should be considered "temporary" during development process.

Comment: That's a good suggestion but propably my knowledge is to poor to manage it in the new way. In details I did that way: I used nuget manager and install library localy in project on my PC. So nuget manager automaticaly put dll into bin. When I saw new files I just copied them to the bin folder on server.

Comment: When I red your suggestion I make another folder called BinPackages and copy new libraries into it. Next, I added reference to project by Website->Add reference -> Browse. But the path is local, so it won't be work in the server. So how to "move" reference to server? Or maybe is there any way to reference on server side?

Comment: When you build, the .dll's should copy to the bin folder. All referenced .dlls no matter where they exist should then as a result get copied to the bin folder. However, it sounds like you have a web site, and not a web site application.  See my above edit - I show a screen cap. It is possible you don't have the "copy local" settting?

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. You're right, it's website, not web app and I don't see in the tree References and I don't have possibility to check properties like on your screen and don't have _copy local_ setting,. I am also using AjaxControlToolkit and other libraries. I tried to add ClosedXML library by adding reference and make build process, and after copying dll from Bin folder to server, but only local I am able to use this in code. Normally I am not using build process, just change code on developing PC and upload files into server.

Comment: As you suggest I can also use App_Code (have few classes there) but when I'm looking at the source code on github I'm not sure which files should be use (espacialy when I'm working with VB, and there's only CS, but it's not matter). However dll's in bin should work anyway.

Comment: Well, as noted, I don't use 'web sites'. But, just looking at one? Well, yes in fact you ARE and it is "normal" practice to put the .dll's in the bin folder (my apologies - as this is the common and correct approach.  So, use project->Add Reference. Browse to that .dll. it should add a reference into web.config (under assemblies group), and it should also then copy  the .dll's over to the bin folder.

Comment: Not problem at all. Even if I don't have specific details of error, I supposed that all libiaries I've tried was too new for my old website. I had to do a lot of digging to find library that is compatibile with ASP.net 2.0 website.